# One column index vs 2 column index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to execute the next delete query:

```
delete from MyTable where userId = 5
```

What of the below indexed will have better performance on this query, or will they both perform the same?

***All the mentioned fields in here are BigInt***

1. `CREATE INDEX MyTable_UserId_UserBalance_index ON Main.dbo.MyTable (UserId, UserBalance);`
2. `CREATE INDEX MyTable_UserId_index ON Main.dbo.MyTable (UserId);`

Comment: Better asked on dba.stackexchange.com, perhaps?

Comment: The first index, having larger entries, will have fewer entries per page and may require more reads. More important is the overall performance of the system. If you throw indexes in to try to optimize each individual query then you will impact queries that have to update all those indexes. See [premature optimization](http://xkcd.com/1691/).

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush this is one of those areas which sort of overlaps these two stack forums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that particular query they should perform roughly the same.  Since you're looking up the first item in the compound index, finding the records should be the same as if there were another index on the single column.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised at many of the answers here - for the purpose of deletion, there won't be ***any*** benefit using either one of these indexes over the other. For if the record exists in either index, you'll need to find it and remove it.

The purpose of indexes is for reads, not deleting data. If you're trying to read data, you would ask a question like this one, as one index has the potential to return the data quicker than the other. For deletes, you need to delete from *all* indexes, including the NC indexes.

It seems as if some enlightenment into the world of indexes is being called for.

> Some great (free) documentation from well-known DBA - Brent Ozar: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/10/think-like-engine-class-now-free-open-source/

Comment: Also, the answer to all questions of this form is: testing.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft you bet! and without seeing an execution plan, thereby knowing what fields the engines is requestion etc. there's little which one can answer - as that would be a shot in the dark

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE INDEX MyTable_UserId_index ON Main.dbo.MyTable (UserId);
```

Comment: please provide an explanation to why do you think it will perform better

Comment: If UserId is not unique per row, then there could be multiple index entries to search. If it is unique, there would be only one index entry to search at (UserId) but using  (UserId, UserBalance) may mutliply the entries if multiple balances are available. Even unique however, the (UserId, UserBalance) index will have more size per entry thus need more time to delete (and insert) so more disk I/O.

Comment: Plus updates (which are deletes+inserts actually) where the 2 field index will need to change if balance changes. More disk I/O. All those will not happen if UserBalance is not part of the index.

Answer (score 0):

Both the indexes would work the same way unless the order is reversed for below index.

From:

```
CREATE INDEX MyTable_UserId_UserBalance_index ON Main.dbo.MyTable (UserId, UserBalance);
```

To:

```
CREATE INDEX MyTable_UserId_UserBalance_index ON Main.dbo.MyTable (UserBalance, UserId);
```

In second case, server may not see this index as useful as UserId is at second level.

Also, why would you create two indexes with same column in it? If you know that your table will be queried frequently with both UserId and UserBalance then, probably it is best to create an index with both columns in it.

*Again, just make sure which column gets utilized the most.*